# How to fix jquery datatables from overflowing outside parent div in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, datatables, overflow

I am using datatables and my html table is sitting inside of a parent div.  I originally had this issue where the table was overflowing outside the parent div like this:

[image]

I found [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571017/how-do-i-fix-long-column-value-issue-which-breaks-table-outside-of-container-us) to add this css:

```
#myTable {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

#myTable td {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

that worked beautifully to fix the issue . . in Firefox and Chrome.  So for those browsers, I now see this:

[image]

but Internet Explorer (I am using IE 11), still unfortunately still shows the overflow issue as in the first picture above. For other browsers, even if I add additional columns, they keep getting squeezed but still fit into the parent div (which is what I want) where IE will just keep growing horizontally

Are there any recommendations for how I can get Internet Explorer to ensure that the table stays inside the parent div and doesn't overflow outside of it?

Here is my heading row html if that helps to show how i am trying to constrain column sizes:

```
    <table  id="myTable" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 22px;">Id</th>
            <th style="max-width: 250px" class="nameColumn">Name</th>
            <th class="descColumn">Description</th>
            <th style="width: 40px;">Status</th>
            <th style="width: 38px;">Start</th>
            <th style="width: 38px;" class="singleLine">End</th>
            <th style="width: 45px;" class="sourceColumn">Source</th>
            <th class="ragColumn">RAG</th>
            <th style="width: 50px;" class="ownerColumn">Owner</th>
            <th class="minorDateColumn singleLine">Prev End</th>
            <th class="minorDateColumn singleLine">Orig End</th>                
            <th style="width: 40px;">Category</th>
            <th style="width: 25px;max-width: 25px">Ref</th>
            <th style="width: 16px;max-width: 16px">Est</th>
            <th class="milestoneCommentsColumn">Comments</th>
            <th style="width: 5px;max-width: 5px">D</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
```

and here is my datatables javascript initialization:

```
    var result = $("#myTable")
        .DataTable({
            "paging": false,
            "ordering": true,
            "stripeClasses": ['evenColor', 'oddColor']
        });
    result.order.neutral().draw();
    dataTable.draw();
    dataTable.columns.adjust().draw();
}
    return result;
```

Comment: Is your IE11 running in IE11 mode? Look in the Developer Tools (F12), "Emulation" tab.

Comment: Could you provide any test code like Jsfiddle ? It will be more easiest to give you an answer.

Comment: I believe I know the answer to this question (as I've faced a similar problem before). But I can't know for sure unless you post all the relevant code... 8 years on Stack Overflow, 16K rep, 225 gold badges.. and a question with no [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Wow! That's gotta be a record of some sort ;-)

Comment: provide code in jsfiddle

Comment: I think this post will get you the answer. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058109/jquery-datatable-overflow-and-text-wrapping-issues

Comment: @Aroniaina - added my html and my javascript datatable initialization if that helps

Comment: @Michael_B - added my html and my javascript datatable initialization if that helps

Answer (score 34):

I've tried to replicate your issue which could be caused by many things, but seems to be something specific of the way you're using `datatables` and not something of a generic `<table>` element.

Please try using this CSS on your code. It's *ugly* as everytime you need to use `!important` but the only way I've ran onto this behaviour is when DataTables calculates the width of the elements in a wrong way, for example once you try to call their method `.adjust()` so we need to programatically overwrite it with our very own CSS (that's why the !important).

```
#myTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100% !important;
}
#myTable td,
#myTable th{
  width: auto !important;
  white-space: normal;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Since the html is pretty long, I've added the code on a jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/zsts5r0m/6/. Check that I'm wrapping it on a container with a max-width. If you were to remove the !important declarations, you see that the issue arises; on all browsers. This fiddle works perfectly on IE11 and Chrome alike.

If this is not working on your table, I'm afraid that while we'd love to help you, we cannot do it unless you share a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of how you're doing it.

Comment: if you are using responsive datatables, this solution doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

Tables headers and cells are `word-break: normal` by default. This leads to no-breaking in a lot of instances.

Try specifying the `word-break` property. IE supports `break-all`, but not `break-word`.

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#no_overflow th, #no_overflow td {
  word-break: break-all; /* IE supports this */
  word-break: break-word; /* IE doesn't support, and will ignore */
  /* http://caniuse.com/#feat=word-break */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <table id="overflow">
    <thead><tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th><th>Col 4</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td><td>Cell 4</td></tr></tbody>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <table id="no_overflow">
    <thead><tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th><th>Col 4</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td><td>Cell 3</td><td>Cell 4</td></tr></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this seems to have the text expand beyond the background

Comment: @leora The first table is without my "fix". The second table is with. On my browser (Chrome 52 & IE11), the second table does not expand beyond the background.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
#Table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100% !important;
}
#Table td{
  width: auto !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#Table th{
  width: auto !important;
  white-space: normal;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Follow the two steps

1. Put you table code in div
2. add table-responsive (Bootstrap class) on that div.

E.g   <div class="table-responsive>
your table

Comment: Does OP use bootstrap?

Comment: Also that example snippet contains a typo.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.  The DataTable never goes outside of the parent div (box-body in this example).

```
<div class="box-body">
    <table id="CustomerTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="cursor:pointer;width:100%">
        <thead style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Return Id</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>SSN</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>      
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is  the solution  the class=box-body or thead style="width:100%" , all cannot work for me

Answer (score 0):

A while back i also tried to set some td properties but IE11 just seemed to ignore them until i also set the property on the table element directly.
So You could try doing this:

```
#myTable {
    table-layout: fixed;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#myTable td {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```